# Envoy Laravel run forever

Tags: laravel, bitbucket-pipelines, laravel-envoy

i'm using bitbucket pipeline to deploy and run some artisan command, 
but there is a problem that make me headache, when artisan command failed, envoy show the error/Exception, but not continue to run next envoy task.it's keep show me the exception till i kill the php process in vps server (using kill/pkill command)

here is my envoy

```html
@task('start_check_log', ['on' => 'web'])
    cd /home/deployer/mywork/laravel/
    nohup bash -c "php artisan serve --env=dusk.local 2>&1 &" && sleep 2
    curl -vk http://localhost:8000 &
    php artisan check_log
    sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8000)
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan config:clear
@endtask
```

`php artisan check_log` just to check the log file, i want to check if error occurred, but when error comes up, envoy stuck on that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this problem, this is just my stupid, I 've to add command pipe in other to envoy continue the task `php artisan check_log && sleep 2`  and the envoy continue  the process

Comment: Please, select your own answer as the accepted answer.